# How many of the parthenogenesis-capable animals came to the Noah's Ark

Tags: science, parashat-noach

How many of the animals that are capable of [parthenogenesis](http://oceanadventures.co.za/parthenogenesis/) (being able to reproduce without a male and female, e.g. the Komodo dragon) did Noach take with him into the Ark - 1 or 2?

Comment: Note that although there have been instances of komodo dragons being capable of parthenogenesis, the common way for them to mate is with a male and female. (Sorry just a nitpick there.)

Comment: You'd also lose the male line completely, so half of the species would be lost forever...

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Actually that's not necessarily true, because at least in the case with the komodo dragon being capable of parthenogenesis, all the babies were male. ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon#Parthenogenesis)) So on the contrary you may have a chance of losing the _female_ line.

Comment: @ezra in the case where only male babies are born, you'd lose the entire species...

Answer (score 3):

Since the Torah doesn't mention a distinction, it's fair to assume that he brought two of each. Even such species usually mate with another individual, in order to reap the evolutionary gains of greater genetic diversity.